# Как хранить такие объекты?

Tags: php, ооп, архитектура

С некого источника, получаю список контрагентов.
Для дальнейшей работы с этими контрагентами, хочу завести сущность Контрагент.
Столкнулся с такой, архитектурной проблемой:

Список контрагентов приходят в XML, сами контрагенты имеют сырые данные, т.е.,
примерно 50 свойств, такого формата:

```
Статус контрагента:  принимает значения 1, 2, 3
Тип контрагента:  принимает значения ind, legal
и т.д.
```

Т.е. значения свойств - это некие ключи, а каким ключам, какие значение соответствуют - описаны в документации (в перечень могут в будущем добавлять какие-то новые ключи, и соответственно должна быть возможность без особых трудностей добавить изменение в код).

1. Как лучше организовать архитектурно, чтобы с этим можно было гибко работать ?
   В каким виде хранить значения всех ключей свойств ? Отдельным объектом ? Или в каком-то конфигурационном файле, например yaml ?
2. Лучше сразу в сущности Контрагента хранить значения, или хранить только ключи, а когда нужны данные, использовать какой-то дополнительный метод, который достает его из конфиг файла ?
3. Какие варианты есть ?

таких объектов может быть несколько, например, у контрагента есть менеджер, со своими свойствами, соответственно, менеджер - тоже отдельная сущность, которая будет у контрагента.

Как насчет что-то похожее на ValueObject ?

```
abstract class DataValue {

  private $values = [];
  private $code;

  public function __construct(string $code) {
    $this->code = $code;
    $this->values = $this->getCodeValues();
  }

  public function getValue() {
    return $this->values[$this->code] ?? null;
  }

  public function getCode(): string {
    return $this->code;
  }

  abstract public function getCodeValues(): array;

}

class CounterpartyStatus extends DataValue {
  public function getCodeValues(): array {
    return [
      "ind" => "Индивидуальный предприниматель",
      "le" => "Юр. лицо"
    ];
  }
}

class Counterparty {

  private $status;

  public function __construct(string $statusCode) {
    $this->status = new CounterpartyStatus($statusCode);
  }

  public function getStatus(): DataValue {
    return $this->status;
  }

}

$counterparty = new Counterparty("le");
$counterparty->getStatus()->getValue();
```

Код не проверял - просто для примера.

Comment: в последнее время СО совсем затух...

Comment: Храните статусы в виде констант. Если объекты хранятся в базе данных, то статусы лучше хранить в объекте.

Comment: @ArchDemon в контрагенто примерно 50 свойств, у половины из низ, помогут быть от 2 до 10 значений.
Это сколько же констант надо..

Comment: 25 * 6 = 150 в среднем. Ничего страшного. Распихайте константы по классам. В каждом классе будет от 2 до 10 констант. Вообще не страшно